# Lambda Edge returns html page instead of json

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am using a AWS cloudfront distribution and configuring a lambda edge function to proxy requests to my non edge based lambda.

I am seeing that the request is being sent correctly when console logging the request to the 2nd lanbda, when triggered from the cloudfront website. Although instead of the request just returning the response body from the 2nd lambda request, it seems the lambda edge returns html of a not found page, as it if was trying to find the html page of the route and not returning and ending execution when the 2nd lambda gives a response.

I am use to working with Cloudflare workers, where this is the behavior, when proxying requests and just returning the response object.

This lambda is configured using the Viewer Request (have also tried origin request).

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
const requestURI = request.uri;

if (requestURI == "/test") {
 const resp = await fetch("example.com"{
 headers: {
   origin:"2ndlambdaurl.example.com"
 },
});
  const respBody = await resp.json();
  return {
   status: '200',
   statusDescription: 'OK'
   headers: {
   'content-type':[{ 
             key:'Content-Type',
             value:'application/json'
 }],
 }
  }
     return request;
 }
```

What is it I am missing here.